ArcGIS how to create a spatially explicit overlay grid in decimal degrees instead of meters
I am attempting to create a 10 x 10 m grid overlay in ArcMap that is spatially explicit with GPS coordinates for each grid corner. Here you can see an example of an overlay that was done that created the desired grid using a meters based coordinate system.


This was done using the "Measured Grid" function within the "Grid Tool" of ArcMap.

I then used the meters coordinate system accompanying the grid (pictured above) to manually create a spreadsheet of points (in meters) to project onto the grid vertices to allow for upload to handheld GPS units for use in the field.

However, our handheld GPS units use decimal degrees for coordinate systems not meters. We therefore cannot upload these points to our handhelds.
To address this, I attempted to use the "Graticule" and "Reference Grid" functions within the "Grid Tool" to make a coordinate system using decimal degrees. Neither of these solutions worked as they do not create grids that are spatially explicit with coordinates.
My questions are:

Is it possible to create a grid in ArcMap with associated decimal degree coordinate system? If so, is there a function for extracting GPS coordinates from the vertices of the grid?
Is it possible to create a grid in ArcMap with associated decimal degree coordinate system? If so, is there a function for extracting GPS coordinates from the vertices of the grid?
If not, is there a way to convert meters to decimal degrees outside of ArcMap?

Here are the are the details of the projection and coordinate system used. Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

